# Convert object fields to array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document Event with a field metrics that is a flat key-value hash of metric name (string) and metric value (float):

```
{ 
  ...
  'metrics': {
    'metric1': 123.32,
    'metric2': 453.32,
    'metric3': 12.32,
  }
}
```

I would like to convert that to an array of values in order to calculate the minimum. How could I do it in mongo?

Comment: Generally speaking it's a bad idea to have dynamic key in the collection. That being said to do this you can use `mapReduce`

Comment: Thanks, the longer I think about it, the more I am convinced that the problem might be with the data structure I've chosen.